# How youtube is preventing browser to sleep on iPhone?

Tags: ios, video, youtube, wakelock

#### Environments

- iOS 14.4.2 (safari)
- chrome 91.4472.80

As I was trying to find a way to prevent my iPhone going to sleep while a browser page is opened, I found 3 ways.

1. use Screen Wake Lock API
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Wake_Lock_API
2. call `window.location.href` periodically and stop it
3. play a video with a user interaction

For #1, this doesn't work on iPhone, should work on Android.
#2, didn't seem to work on either safari or chrome on iPhone.
#3, also didn't work (even playing a video after user interaction).

I tried https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js/ but didn't prevent from sleeping.
I also tried https://github.com/roldanjr/use-stay-awake and it opened a blank video in fullscreen (this maybe fixed by just adding https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-playsinline)

Then, I noticed browser version of Youtube preventing my phone from sleeping while it's playing a video (I set my sleep time for 30 seconds, and it can play a 10 min video without turning itself off).

Does anyone know what kind of technics they are using to do that?

Comment: Did you find out how youtube is doing it?

Comment: https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js/  This actually is working for me.   https://gist.github.com/github0013/7bba37c108cb8983ff3f0dd2f7102cc7  This is how I am using it.